# capistrano 3.5 use git https repo

Tags: git, http, authentication, https, capistrano

i have a an server where i want to deploy my source code via capistrano.
i can acces a deployment user via ssh on this server, but the repo i am pulling from is actually only accessible via https. 
I am using capistrano 3.5  and

cap staging doctor

shows the following in variables. There may be more than standard cap, but i think what they do is obvious.

Variables

```
:application                 "capistrano_deployment"
:branch                      "master"
:default_env                 {}
:deploy_prefix               ""
:deploy_root                 "/var/www"
:deploy_to                   "/var/www/capistrano_deployment"
:format                      :airbrussh
:git_environmental_variables {:git_askpass=>"/bin/echo", :git_ssh=>"/tmp/capistrano_deployment/git-ssh.sh"}
:keep_releases               5
:local_user                  "myuser"
:log_level                   :debug
:pty                         true
:repo_url                    "https://myuser@git.internal.net/git/capistrano_deployment.git"
:scm                         :git
:stage                       :staging
:target_directory            "capistrano_deployment"
:tmp_dir                     "/tmp"
```

the problem i have is that the deployment fails, because capistrano doesn't ask me for a password for git this repository, which is accessed by https and *not* as capistrano seems to assume via ssh.

```
 INFO [ce69c094] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads https://myuser@git.internal.net/git/capistrano_deployment.git as deploy@…
DEBUG [ce69c094] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/capistrano_deployment/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remo…
DEBUG [ce69c094]       fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://myuser@git.internal.net/git/capistrano_deployment.git/'
```

What do i need to change that capistrano ask for a password for the https url -  and hopefully only once and not for every git query, which is executed by capistrano?
Also there seems to be solution to deploy the username and password in .netrc in cleartext (NOT AN OPTION!). Want to avoid such a solution at all cost

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a password via Capistrano like this:

```
set :git_http_password, "secret"
```

Or prompt the Capistrano user for it like this:

```
ask :git_http_password
```

Unfortunately, all this really does is put the password in plaintext in the repository URL. That means it will be echoed in the logs and perhaps other places.

Source: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/4406674cd324a714c14a52554300aa721fb2b2b7/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb#L38-L53

Probably not what you want, but I believe this is the only option available to you if you want to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Matt's answer to work, even though the code is still inside Capistrano. But instead of trying to figure out I went for getting Capistrano itself to ask for the username and password. Add this to config/deploy.rb:

```
ask(:github_user_name, nil)
ask(:github_password, nil)

set :repo_url, "https://#{fetch(:github_user_name)}:#{fetch(:github_password)}@github.com/github-account-name/my-repo.git"
```